# Switch Round Robins/Americano Algorithm in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, round-robin

Just as part of my hobby, I'm try to build a scheduler where you enter N number of players in the system, and it will generate an array of combinations. For example

```
players = ['A','B','C','D','E']
players.combination(2).to_a

# ["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["A", "D"], ["A", "E"], ["B", "C"], ["B", "D"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "D"], ["C", "E"], ["D", "E"]]
```

Then I would like my generate_matches functions to take this array of pairs, and turn this into matches where teach pair only plays once AND players of course cannot play themselves. This should work on a minimum 4 players, and work for every number above 4 whether it's odd or even.

I thought of it to be a simple issue to solve, but I've been just in a rabbit hole.

See pseudocode & code below:

```
    # select random team
    # find team that does not contain one of the players
    # create match between team 1 and team 2
    # delete team 1 and team 2 from original array
    # repeat until no team left
```

```
def generate_matches(player_combinations)
   matches = []

   while !player_combinations.empty?
        team_1 = player_combinations.shift

        # if team doesn't include any of the team 1 player, select them
        filtered_teams = player_combinations.select do |team| 
            (team & team_1).empty? 
        end
        team_2 = filtered_teams.pop

        player_combinations.delete(team_2)
        matches << [team_1, team_2]
    end

    matches
end
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    [['C','B'], ['A','E']],
    [['E','D'], ['B','A']],
    [['A','C'], ['D','B']],
    [['B','E'], ['C','D']],
    [['D','A'], ['E','C']],
]
```

Actual Result:

```
[
    [["A", "C"], ["D", "E"]], 
    [["C", "D"], ["B", "E"]], 
    [["A", "B"], ["C", "E"]], 
    [["B", "C"], ["A", "E"]]
]
```

This should result in equal amount of matches for players, however it doesn't. I'm really confused why. See results after running it a few times:

```
Key Represents Player
Value represents # games they played
{"A"=>4, "C"=>3, "B"=>2, "E"=>4, "D"=>3}

But it should actually be:
{"A"=>4, "C"=>4, "B"=>4, "E"=>4, "D"=>4}
```

Sometimes it's just dumb luck, and I do get the correct answer. Most of the times, I don't. I guess I think too simple about this problem

Comment: What's your expected `matches` result for the example pairs in your question?

Comment: Expected matches result example added

Comment: In case of an odd number number of players, just introduce a "DUMMY" player.

Comment: Hmm, even with an even number of players, I'm running into an issue where I don't get the correct result. So let's say we have 8 players, this would result in 28 combinations. This should technically result in 14 matches, however my code sometimes returns 12, 13 matches and sometimes the correct number of matches.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Wikipedia has an [round robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) lemma which contains an algorithm.

Comment: Hmm still a bit stuck. Round robin tournament algorithm makes sense, but when I try to apply it I just don't end up in the right result. I think it might have to do with the way I pick the pairs from the array of pairs until there is none left.